# Did pirates talk the way they are currently portrayed?

Tags: history

Where did the common pop-culture way of portraying pirates ([yarr!](http://www.yarr.org.uk/talk/)) come from? Did pirate captains commonly have birds on their shoulders?

Comment: This question would be much awesomer with a [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Piratey%2C_vector_version.svg/500px-Piratey%2C_vector_version.svg.png)!

Comment: Avast! Don't forget, __September 19th__ is [Talk like a pirate day](http://www.talklikeapirate.com/piratehome.html) ;)

Comment: Question should have been asked using pirate talk.

Comment: @Sklivvz - that is OBVIOUSLY not a picture of a real pirate. No  pirate would keep their cutlass in such horrid state.

Comment: The cliche pirate accent (with all the "arrrr"s) is the accent of the Cornwall district of Great Britain -- traditionally the location of the ports used by (English) pirates. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country_dialects

Comment: 'common pop-culture way' in the US? I don't know such portrays. Can you name and show examples, and explain, how many of them are in the cited way, whether it is a majority. And since you talk about pirates in past tense - why don't actual pirates count? Where do you cut the line? Are pirates from the antique excluded as well? From Indochina? Somalia?

Comment: This was discussed over at [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/pirate-speech-basis-in-fact)! There is at least [one primer on pirate language](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1582974896) that is backed with actual references from pirates.

Comment: Related question: [Pirates with a prosthetic hook: Lore or Truth?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/944/pirates-with-a-prosthetic-hook-lore-or-truth)

Comment: YARRRRRR!!!!!!!

Comment: And when did they switch from "Yarr.. matey" to "31337 h4x0r3d u" ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2729/why-are-pirates-depicted-with-a-parrot-on-their-shoulder:

> **Piratespeak**. "Arrrr" showed up late, probably in movies of the 1930s. Actor Robert Newton played Silver in the 1950 version of  Treasure Island, one of the better portrayals of old-school piracy, and reprised the role in sequels and on TV; his accent featured a strong rolling R, which likely helped fix "arrrr" in the piratical canon. **Much pirate lingo, like "avast," was simply nautical speech of the time; "shiver my timbers" predates Stevenson, but he ran with it.**

To specifically prove "avast" mentioned above, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avast says:

> Etymology: From the Dutch hou' vast (“hold fast”), from houd (“hold”) + vast (“fast”)

---

As far as parrots - the above linked straightdope article didn't really have enough level of details, but this blog does: http://pirates2.sakraft.com/labels/History.html (*Of Pirates and Parrots; Thursday, June 19, 2008*) as well as "[Parrots in History](http://avianenrichment.com/fun_history.htm)" page which quotes from that blog and adds its own info:

> ```
> Pirates and Parrots?
> ```
>
> By the time of the Golden Age of Piracy (1680 – 1730) there was a well established trade in parrots.  Usually animals aboard a ship were used as provisions rather than as pets but fortunately parrots weren’t a favorite meal.
>
> It is thought that the pirate & parrot cliché originated from Robert Louis Stevenson’s “Treasure Island”.
>
> However, the historical journal of Pirate Captain William Dampier describes that in certain cases pirates actually did take parrots on board, most likely because they wanted to sell them at a profit to the high society of Europe. In Dampier's journal it is mentioned that parrots were stored along with other animals and provisions on the ship, while anchoring at a Caribbean island:
>
> "*The tame Parrots we found here were the largest and fairest Birds of their kind that I ever saw in the West Indies. Their colour was yellow and red, very coursly mixt; and they would prate very prettily; and there was scarce a Man but what sent aboard one or two of them. So that with Provision, Chests, Hencoops and Parrot-Cages, our Ships were full of Lumber, with which we intended to sail.*"

Comment: I suspect real pirates were a whole lot less charming than they are portrayed.

Comment: your dutch translation is a tad confusing, since vast is closer to fastening (fast as in tight). the way wiki states it makes me see it as in fast = quick (or related to speed.) and i've never heard fast used the way the wiki does it around where i live.  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vast#Dutch

Comment: @Andy - could it have been an effect of changing usage over time?

Comment: @Andy: it's an anachronism, actually. Modern English doesn't really use "fast" to mean "tight", but somewhat earlier modern English did.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey having met several enterprising seafaring folk around the world who would auto- and reasonably qualify as modern day pirates, I suspect that pirates of old were by their communal ad-hoc nature quite a bit funnier, socially adept, and resilient than the Hollywood portrayals. Not to glorify it, but the necessities of the land and community demanded in those days quite a bit higher of a standard than what could be portrayed by feature film and accepted by Western audiences.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: Interesting, and I thought [*this*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1T8M6cp3-o) was enlightening, and [*this*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWRZfixUJik), if it's true.

Comment: @Ernie You'll still find that usage in phrases such as "to hold fast". Not really used in colloquial dialogue, but still present in the language.

Comment: @JAB &Ernie also any _fast_eners.